# Batch Script at Startup not Completing

Tags: windows, batch-file, startup

I have a batch script to pull down the latest revision files from an SVN that runs at Windows startup (configured with local group policy editor).

Here is the code for the script:

```
@echo off

if "%1"=="" (
    set LIBPATH=C:\ALTIUM_WORK\00001_MCHP-CDB\parts\Library
) else (
    set LIBPATH=%1
)

svn cleanup %LIBPATH%

set DATETIME=%DATE:~4,2%/%DATE:~7,2%/%DATE:~10,4% %TIME:~0,2%:%TIME:~3,2%:%TIME:~6,2%

echo %DATETIME%>mcl_update.log
svn up %LIBPATH%>>mcl_update.log

if ERRORLEVEL 1 goto ERRHANDLER
Exit

:ERRHANDLER
<Insert error message here>
```

When I run this script by double-clicking the .bat, I get the following output in mcl_update.log:

```
02/14/2017 16:13:50
Updating 'C:\ALTIUM_WORK\00001_MCHP-CDB\parts\Library':
At revision 5800.
```

This is what I expect, but when the script runs at startup, the last line is left out.  It populates mcl_update.log with this:

```
02/14/2017 16:16:07
Updating 'C:\ALTIUM_WORK\00001_MCHP-CDB\parts\Library':
```

The second line is part of the output from `svn`, so it seems like the command starts, but just never finishes.  I'm at a loss for why this is happening.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

-Sean

A newly-discovered bit of info:  After startup, if I try to delete the log file that is generated, Windows throws an error stating that "The action can't be completed because the file is open in cmd.exe".

Is it possible that this could be a domain issue?  The connection to my company's network isn't up yet, so the `svn` command just hangs?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `path` is not what you are expecting during start-up. Perhaps you should explicitly specify the path for `svn` because the only report you are apparently logging is a plain `echo`, not any reponse from `svn`.

Comment: `Updating 'C:\ALTIUM_WORK\00001_MCHP-CDB\parts\Library':` is the first part of the `svn` output, though.  It just never seems to complete the command.

Just as a sanity check, I added a `cd` to `svn`'s path first, but the output is the same thing.  Unless I need to use an explicit path in calling `svn`.

Comment: If you suspect it's a timing issue, perhaps inserting a `timeout /t 90 >nul` before the first `svn` may reveal. Otherwise, I'd add a `pause` after the second (problematic) `svn` and remove the redirection. I suspect that `svn` is waiting for input and possibly reporting on `stderr` so the prompt won't appear on `stdout` for redirection. It's interesting that the first `svn` appears to complete. `2>&1` should redirect stderr and stdout to the file with your current redirectors (but that won't help with any input that `svn` may be waiting upon)

Answer (score 0):

So after following @Magoo's suggestion of piping `stderr` out to the file, the issue became clear.  It turns out it has to do with my server's user authentication.  Since the script was running at startup (i.e. before I logged in), the `svn` command wouldn't work, as user authentication was impossible.

I changed the group policy to start the script at logon, rather than startup, and everything works now.